# List view resetting when returning to page?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using Android Studio to make an app and in the app I have a page that contains a list that you add items to. Everything works fine but when I leave the page and return the list has disappeared? How do I make it so when I come back to the page the list I made earlier is displayed?

```
package com.example.graded_unit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        // Displays costs
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Expense Value", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Float number = sharedPref.getFloat("Expense Value",0);
        TextView costView = findViewById(R.id.costView);
        String cost = Float.toString(number);
        costView.setText("£" + cost);

        ListView listView;

        //Creates bar at the top with title of page and back button
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test List");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        //Assigns ListView to the list on the design page
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        //Creates an array list for strings
        final ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        //Creates an array adapter for the arrayList
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(Test.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

        //Sets the adapter to the listView so you can view the list on the page
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



        //Creates the button for adding a new item to the list
        FloatingActionButton addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText testCost = findViewById(R.id.testCost);
                EditText testText = findViewById(R.id.testText);
                String cost = testCost.getText().toString();
                String expense = testText.getText().toString();

                //Adds expense to the list with a toast to confirm
                arrayList.add(expense + ": £" + cost);
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Added " + expense + ": £" + cost + " to the list!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Float costs = Float.parseFloat(cost);

                //Saves the total expenses value
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Expense Value", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                Float test = sharedPref.getFloat("Expense Value", 0);
                costs = costs + test;
                editor.putFloat("Expense Value", costs);
                editor.apply();

                //Displays the total expenses value at the top
                TextView costView = findViewById(R.id.costView);
                String expenseValue = costs.toString();
                costView.setText("£" + expenseValue);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the code to access the activity

```
Button expensesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expensesBtn);
        expensesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Account.this, Test.class));
            }
        });
```

To access the activity with the list in it I have a button on another page that starts that activity. 
I am new to Java and Stack Overflow to sorry if I have given too much code or not enough.

Comment: can you post the code for how you are moving out of your activity and coming back to it ?

Comment: The code to move out of the activity is already there I use getSupportActionBar to make a back button that you can click

Comment: everything looks good, can you check logs when you are returning to your activity

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: can you check logcat when you return to your activity ? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: @Logic Yeah I can?

Answer (score 2):

You need save the information from arraylist and load this information when you enter in page (onCreate method)

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    //Load information from database/sharedpreferene/file wherever
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList = getExpensiveList();

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Test.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    .
    .
}
```

You can save the information everytime that you add a new Item or Listened the action onBackButton.

```
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .
            .
            saveExpesiveList(arrayList);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I actually save the list and load it though?

Comment: [This is an example:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences-on-android)  You can find how load and save arraylist in sharedPreference. They are using gson and save a String. 
Or you can use a local database with sqlLite

Comment: Sorry I'm new to java and can't seem to get it working, is there anyway you can post some example code or something?